# Padding top element on hover in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I've tried to `padding-top` on hover element `ul#top li a` but it fails to excute the code, maybe the inline-block display is bothering the padding to display but I dont know any other display to help him be inline and able him padding-top.
Incase my target is not understandable, I'm trying to padd "a" tag on hover to the top (about 5px padding).

Here is my CSS Code:

```
ul#top{
       list-style: none;
}
ul#top li{
       display: inline-block;
       padding-right: 30px;
}
ul#top li a{
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
        transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
}
ul#top li a:hover{
       padding-top: 10px;
       color: green;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul id="top">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

How to enable padding-top in inline-block display? (The inline-block might not be the problem, but I think it is)

Comment: try this padding-top: 10px !important;

Comment: @SaiRamSudheer its not it.. any other suggestions?

Comment: So, when you hover over the link, you want it to change color to green and then shift downward by 10px and all the other links stay as is?

Comment: @MarcAudet Exactly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `bottom: 10px` instead with `position: relative`. Also add `padding-bottom` for an issue on hover:

```css
ul#top {
    list-style: none;
}
ul#top li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
ul#top li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
}
ul#top li:hover a {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;/*Add padding bottom*/
    color: green;
    bottom: 10px;/*Add bottom 10px*/
}
body {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul id="top">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">test</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! though you might conside change top to bottom because negative pixels can be a problem in the future.

Comment: Quick fix. Updated. Adding padding-bottom for this issue you describe.

Comment: hmm what do you mean? And can you send me a fiddle with the issue please?

Comment: I mean when I hover the link it will padd in slower effect

Comment: You want to move smoother?

Comment: Yes, I do want it to move smoother.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61844/discussion-between-alex-char-and-exclusiv3).